Can we use a hook on React Server Component?
I know that we cannot use hook inside RSC (React Server Components) but playing with https://github.com/ixartz/Next-js-Boilerplate
I can see server pages (within /app folder) which are using this code:
import { useTranslations } from 'next-intl';


export default function DashboardLayout(props: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const t = useTranslations('DashboardLayout');
  ...
}

While this page resides in src/app/[locale]/(auth)/dashboard/layout.tsx, it does not contain the "use client" directive on top of the file.
What am I missing here ?
Maybe it only applies to hooks "that depend on state, effects, or browser-only APIs"... ?
Thank you
Maybe someone can share a useful and concise documentation about this ?

depends on the APIs your hooks are using.

useTranslations from next-intl is designed to work in both client and server contexts. It doesn't rely on browser-only APIs, side effects, or client-side state management—things that are restricted in RSC. Instead, it simply retrieves translations, which can be done during the server-side rendering phase without needing client-side interactions.
Certain hooks like useTranslations are designed to work in the server environment because:

They don't manage state or perform side effects.
They only depend on the availability of data at the time of rendering (like fetching translations from the server).

That's why useTranslations can be used in a file that doesn't include the "use client" direct
the next-intl documentation has specific sections about how their API works with server components.
